# Command to extract audio from video without conversion

Tags: audio, video

I know that `flv` and `mp4` files contain `aac` audio, while `avi`video usually `mp3` audio streams.

What command (avconv, ffmpeg) would extract the audio without transcoding it?

Comment: You might be interested in a [PHP script](https://superuser.com/questions/1301901/ffmpeg-how-to-determine-output-extension-automatically-ca-copy/1336570#1336570) I crafted, that I use to automatically determine the extension of the output audio file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audio.aac
```

Here’s a short explanation on what every parameter does:

- `-i` option specifies the input file.
- `-vn` option is used to skip the video part.
- `-acodec copy` will copy the audio stream keeping the original codec.

Comment: while the mp4 video contains aac audio, not mp3, is that keeping the audio stream without transcoding?

Comment: Didn't take care of output file extension, my mistake. Updated the answer. Anyway, if you read the full answer, you will find that -acodec copy, this avoid transcoding.

Comment: i suggest m4a (container for aac) instead of aac, because it seems that is not easy to play

Comment: is it possible, while ussing ffmpeg or avconv, to have a command without mentioning the real names of input/output files, so that the command be used as such? (i would like to use that in a context menu action in nemo file manager)

Comment: You might want to use a variable or something like that, but is better is you ask a question with all specific details.

Comment: [created a specific question on that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170414/32012)

Answer (score 5):

As a complementary answer, with a command that doesn't need the specific name of the file.

For a video containing aac audio:

```
ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a
```

To use in a context menu command, a form like this works:

```
bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -map 0:1 -c:a copy "${0%%.*}".m4a' %f
```

Replace with corresponding audio format output for other video format input.

---

Initial source [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/235912/47206).