# How to add ffmpeg/avconv command to Nemo actions?

Tags: audio, video, multimedia, nemo

I would like to have a command like this one

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audio.m4a
```

into a Nemo action (context menu).

But that would mean using variables instead of real names of files. (Also, preferably, instead of the input extension: I would like a command applicable to different extensions).

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For single user use, you can write a nemo action in:

`$HOME/.local/share/nemo/actions/`

For all users use:

`/usr/share/nemo/actions/`

The file has to preserve the file ending `*.nemo_action`. Something like:

```
[Nemo Action]
Name=mp42m4a
Comment=Convert mp4/flv to m4a
Exec=gnome-terminal -x sh -c "ffmpeg -i %F -vn -acodec copy audio.m4a"
Icon-Name=
Selection=notnone
Extensions=mp4;flv;
```

More examples at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nemo#Nemo_Actions

Complete(?) documentation at: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo/blob/master/files/usr/share/nemo/actions/sample.nemo_action

Comment: It does not work as it is. If I set the terminal to stay open after running the command, I see `F%: No such file or directory`. Also, should be edited to adjust the action so it becomes visible in context menu but only for mp4 and flv. There seems to be a problem with the command itself.

Comment: @cipricus I edited the comment and changed all the errors I could find. Couldn't test, though. For a "changelog" (if the edit gets approved) just click it. Also added some information and ressources from the official nemo repository, which will be helpful to you in the future.

Comment: @Minix - I fear this will have to wait, unless somebody else can test it. I do not use Nemo at the present.

Comment: @cipricus Sure. If you or someone else gets around to testing it, firing a comment at me or zorbax would be appreciated.